# jQuery server-side button

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have a page(ASP.NET 3.5) with a number of buttons, some of them are saving buttons, some are not. I have to be generic, i.e. cannot call individual controls by ID. My save buttons will probably have attribute UserSubmitBehavior = true. In a click event handler I need to distinguish what type of button I pressed, so:

```
$('input[type=submit]').bind('click', function(e)
{
    //need to know how to set up this condition
    if (this.type = "submit")
    {

          //do something here 
    }
    else 
    {
          //do something else

    } 


});
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have multiple types of buttons, both regular and submit. You can do it in one function, like so:

```
$('input[type=submit], input[type=button]').bind('click', function(e)
{
    if ($(this).attr('type') == "submit")
    {
          //do something here 
    }
    else 
    {
          //do something else
    } 
});
```

You can also break it up into a more readable manner though:

```
$('input[type=button]').bind('click', function(e){
   //do button stuff here
});

$('input[type=submit]').bind('click', function(e){
   //do submit stuff here
});
```

Personally, I prefer the second method.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, I like second better so I will try it shortly. I think if I set UseSubmitBehavior=false then it renders as 'button' type, not 'submit'

Answer (score 0):

You could use a css class:

```
<asp:Button CssClass="SubmitButton" ... />
```

and:

```
$('input.SubmitButton').bind( .. );
```

Will this work for you?

Comment: Yes, but then I cannot distinguish non-submit buttons from textboxes on a page

Answer (score 0):

I've done this little trick on occassion where I've needed to identify labels or textboxes within a GridView control. What I'll do is add a custom attribute to help me identify them on the page. For example:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblSpecial" runat="server" Text="Whatever" MyCustomeAttr="SpecialLabel">
<asp:Label ID="lblSpecial2" runat="server" Text="Whatever" MyCustomeAttr="SpecialLabel2">
```

It's fairly simple from there to use JQuery to get at that custom attribute, be it by the .attr() function or by a selector:

```
$("span[id$='_lblSpecial2'][MyCustomeAttr='SpecialLabel2']");
```

Comment: Won't that break XHTML compliance?